# Trying to translate fields of my classes (Django internationalization Cap)

Tags: python, django, django-models, internationalization, django-views

Today i am translating my training project, yesterday i was reading The Django book (Cap: Internationalization) and i have achieved translate my templates completely. Now I have a new issue. I have some dynamic content that i wanna translate, but **i don't know how proceed** beyond add the pseudonym of ugettext:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
```

In my project the "Products" are my dynamic content, and this is my class:

```
class Product(TimeStampModel):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)
    # Product Images
    pimage0 = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'prodimg')
    pimage1 = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'prodimg')
    pimage2 = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'prodimg')
    pimage3 = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'prodimg')
    # END Product Images
    size = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
    content1 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    content2 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    # Product Stats
    tolerance = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    efficiency = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    performance = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    lowrad = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    # END Product Stats
    # Other Features
    protection = models.TextField(null=True)
    protection1 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    environments = models.TextField()
    environments1 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    # END Other Features
    # Key Features
    kfeature0 = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'kfeats')
    kfeature1 = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'kfeats')
    # END Key Features
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

To render this on a template i use this view:

```
class SingleProView(DetailView):

    template_name = 'products/single_product.html'
    model = Product
```

**I want to translate these fields to spanish:**

*content, content1, content2, protection, protection1, environments, environments1*

Should I modify the models.py or views.py?

currently i have my translations only limited to templates, so that you can freely assume that I've already done the respective *locale* directory configuration, *.po .mo* documents, the middleware, etc (The basic configuration), I only want to translate these fields to spanish.

apologizeme in advance if I overlook something. Any contribution is wellcome, Thanks for evaluate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model translations are not supported by Django out of the box.

Those packages implement that feature:

- [django-hvad](https://github.com/KristianOellegaard/django-hvad)
- [django-modeltranslation](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation)

Comment: Currently i manage my translations with rosetta package, this could bring me some conflict using one of the two packages that you suggested me?

Comment: @Jhonny Rosetta is for translating static strings such as those found in templates, those apps are for translating dynamic content stored in the database, they will not conflict, they do not use the same technology.